# How to reset a css rule to revert a element to its original behavior?

Tags: css, html-lists

first of all, sorry about my english!

I have an <ul> element that is styled by another file and I want reset the element's behavior to its original state: display each <li> element below each other. I tryed clean the inheritance applying a class forcing the <li> display as block elements but doing this doesn't work. Any Ideias how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT to show the code**

```
ul.post-feelings-list {
    display: block;
}
```

I apply this class to an ul previously stylized, and the previous rules dont change. Each li continues appearing inline

Comment: Could you please post your code so we can tell you what needs to be overridden/reverted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for !important.

Say I have two classes:

```
.class1 {
font-size: 13pt;
}

.class2 {
font-size: 10pt !important;
}
```

When both classes are applied, class2 overrides class1 and makes the font size 10pt.

Comment: accully this example would be better if you switch the order. css overrides the last style that was found, so ``important`` comes in handy when ``class2`` is before ``class1`` so with the ``important`` flag the styles from ``class1`` do not override the styles from ``class2``

Answer (score 0):

You could override this style with `!important` but it's not always advised as your code will be less maintainable.

```
ul.post-feelings-list {
  display: block !important;
}
```